# How to run the Kubernetes dashboard on a worker node?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-cluster

I have used the following command to deploy the K8S dashboard:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-beta6/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml

kubectl proxy
```

It says the dashboard runs on the below-mentioned URL on the master node:

> http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

How can I deploy the dashboard on a worker node?

Answer (score 1):

Can you comment or remove the below portion from the YAML

```
      # Comment the following tolerations if Dashboard must not be deployed on master
      tolerations:
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          effect: NoSchedule
```

Comment: dashboard should be deployed on master only . But it should be accessible  from any machine

Comment: then you should update the dashboard service type to NodePort

Comment: externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 32051
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}

Comment: cluster ip is different than master node ip

Comment: In order to access `nodePort` service You need to use `<node IP>:<nodePort>` so 
it should be `32051` and not `8443`.